# Disabling Basic Auth in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to disable basic auth in a spring boot 3 application I use the code below:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) ->
                        authorizeHttpRequests.requestMatchers("/register", "/registerCaptcha").permitAll().
                        anyRequest().denyAll()
                );
        http.csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable());
        http.httpBasic(httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer -> httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer.disable());
        http.cors(c -> {
            CorsConfigurationSource source = request -> {
                CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                config.setAllowedOrigins(List.of(
//                      "*",
                        "http://localhost:4001", "http://127.0.0.1:4001"));
                config.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
                config.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
                return config;
            };
            c.configurationSource(source);
        });
        return http.build();
    }
```

but it does not work, I still get the

```
2024-01-04T22:53:20.722Z  WARN 24568 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration :

Using generated security password: 6f6831fc-b710-4772-aa72-cb1746196b29
```

How Can I disable basic auth? and if it is disabled why the password gets generated? and is there any way to get rid of it?

EDIT per @Toerktumlare request

```
package com.derbyware.registration;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RegistrationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RegistrationApplication.class, args);
    }
```

config

```
package com.derbyware.registration.config;

@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "com.derbyware.registration.proxy")
public class ProjectConfig {

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ProjectConfig.class.getName());

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
```

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.derbyware.resgistration</groupId>
    <artifactId>registration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>registration</name>
    <description>registration</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.70</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2023.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

if there is any other files you need to know let me know.

Comment: if you are getting the default password in the logs means that your entire security configuration bean is not found by spring security during startup, without knowing your folder structure, and your full class file including the location of your main class file and its contents we cant help

Comment: I've added some other code, do need any other source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration as below

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need authentication, then you should remove the spring-boot-starter-security dependency.

The passwords printed in the logs are automatically generated by spring-security. If you still need authentication, you can create a UserDetailsService, implemented with InMemoryUserDetailsManager or JdbcUserDetailsManager.

like this：

```java
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
}
```

Comment: this got rid of the password, but it still does not disable basic auth. it just declare UDS with 0 users.